# Desabilitar botão no menu para não ficar atualizando a página, com Javascript

Tags: html

Gente estou querendo adicionar ao site, uma forma de quando um botão do menu for clicado, ele fique desabilitado, por exemplo ao clicar em Home, o link do botão direciona para a página Home, depois se clicar outra vez em Home a página não atualizar mais, porém ao clicar em Quem Somos, o botão Home volta a ser habilitado.
Estou pesquisando e ainda não encontrei como fazer isso.

Comment: não achou? já pesquisou como salvar/ler cookies? só gravar a informação lá pra saber que quer desabilitar o botão, mesmo ele navegando para várias páginas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente, encontrei uma forma mais fácil, já que vai redirecionado a página com refresh, eu usei session e PHP mesmo. Por ex: Em cima no início da página home.

Em top.php onde fica os botões, em cima.

Home
   
        Home

        Relatório
   
        Relatório

Isso para todos os botões do menu.